# jQuery <select> simulation with input and div

Tags: jquery, select, html, input, focus

I have one input field and one division with span children

```
<input type="text" id="input" name="input" />

<div id="content">
    <span>option 1</span>
    <span>option 2</span>
    <span>option 3</span>
    <span>option 4</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a jQuery simulation of `select` drop-down list.

```
$('#content').hide();
$('#input').focus(function(){
    $('#content').show();
});

$('#content span').click(function(){
    $('#input').val($(this).html())
    $('#content').hide();
});
```

Everything's works fine but I just can't figure it out how to hide div on inputs blur.
If I put this inside jQuery

```
$('#input').blur(function(){
    $('#content').hide();
});
```

then I'm unable to click on span element

Comment: I am really unsure what you are tyring to achieve. Can you point to an example of what you are trying to do? Maybe you have come across something similar on the web.

Comment: I really don't know if there is something similar. I'm trying to be original :) Like I said: I want to simulate html drop-down list. http://jsfiddle.net/NQbgX/

Comment: @Goldie how can you expect to hide the div after blur, and still allow the user to make a selection? All elements within an element that has display:none; will be hidden, regardless of their display state. So this idea is implausible at best.

Comment: That's the beauty of the task. You should not literaly looking for a solution by lookin at the blur function.

Comment: Can anyone please help with this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496709/stopping-a-blur-event-on-click-of-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `setTimeout` like [this](http://jsbin.com/uxerus/2/edit) so that there is just enough time for the  click on the span to register.

Comment: Nice approach but I find it not so user-friendly. I need something that will hide div right after blur.

Comment: @Goldie: adjust the `setTimeout` to a lower value.

Comment: @Goldie: That's nice but I would be wary of the `window.click` or `body.click` potentially interfering with something else in future...

Comment: I have set `setTimeout` to 100 and it looks much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found it
http://jsfiddle.net/NQbgX/1/

```
$('body').click(function(){
    if (!$("#input").is(":focus")) {
        $('#content').hide();
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#content { margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style-type:none; display:none;}
#content li { margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style-type:none;}
#content li a { 
    display:inline-block; 
    padding:10px; 
    text-align:left; 
    color:white; 
    background-color:black;
    text-decoration:none; 
    width:150px;
}
​#input ​{ height:25px; width:167px;}​
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#input').focus(function(){
        $('#content').slideDown('fast');
    });
    $('#content li a').click(function(){
        var x = $(this).attr('title');
        $('#input').attr('value',x);
        $('#content').slideUp('fast');
    }); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input" name="input" value="" />
<ul id="content">
    <li><a href="#" title="option1">Option1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="option2">Option2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="option3">Option3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="option4">Option4</a></li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</body>
</html>
```

Then just add an arrow image beside the input so that the #content will slideUp when its clicked.

Comment: Yes, but div should disappear when you click outside the input and outside the div.