# Selecting div in custom dropdown using Keyboard (Up, down and enter keys)

Tags: jquery, html, keyboard-events, html-select

I have simulated a dropdown look alike using div. I have also implemented search functionality for the values in dropdown div. I am trying to select the options in div dropdown using keys. When i search for a particular query and try to select the options presented, its not working.

Can anyone please suggest solution.

Code present here ---> http://jsbin.com/ujimih/2/edit

Updated code present here ---> http://jsbin.com/ujimih/10/edit

Comment: Could you clarify? When I view the code at above link - and click in the search field - I get a drop-down, which I can then select using my down arrow and hitting enter - is that not what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes. sorry i think my question is not clear.

Comment: Actually what i want is, when the user enters any character in the search field, then the matching results are displayed with other results hidden. The keyboard selection works well for default list. But, when the user enters any character in the field and tries to select the results through keyboard, it does not work properly.